# Initializing a variable which wont reset its value when i swipe pages (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I was wondering if I could initialize a value which would not reset itself when I swipe through pages. For example, I want to set a name on one page and when I swipe back to the page. I'm not looking to make it const or final because the user can re-input a new value.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is called `State` management, that is, the architecture to keep the data consistent between different `Widgets` at different moments in time.

Different strategies apply to different scenarios, the most common being BLoC, among many others.

That said, a simplicistic way to keep a variable data independent from the `Widget`, would be to use a `Singleton`, which in `Flutter` can be created as follows:

```
// file data.dart

library singleton;

Data singleton = new Data();

class Data {
  String title;
}
```

And can be used in any `Widget`:

```
import './data.dart';

void main() {
  Data data = Singleton;
  data.title = "Test";
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Data data = Singleton;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: data.title;
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its alright I think i already found somewhat of a solution using shared preferences. But now I'm getting a problem because shared preferences is async and i need to convert a Future<String> into string.

Comment: You can use `await` such as: `String data = await preferences.getString(‘data’);`